# Does a magnet always reorient itself along the most efficient path?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If a magnet is held in a magnetic field in which it is not in the position of lowest energy, the magnet will tend to reorient itself to align with the field. When reorienting in 3D space, there are an infinite number of paths along which the magnet could rotate to reorient itself to arrive at the same endpoint.

Light always takes the fastest path to its destination. Does a magnet always reorient along the most efficient path of rotation?

Note that typically, the magnet will tend to both **translate** and **rotate** into its ideal position. For the purposes of this question, I'm only interested in the **rotation**, as there is always exactly one vector between the origin and destination point in translation, so there's one logical option for translation, but infinitely paths corresponding to infinitely many options for rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is based on a slight misunderstanding. While it's true that the path taken by a light ray minimises that travel time this is actually an example of a deeper principle called the [principle of least action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action).

If we have a starting point and an end point then with every path between the two points we can calculate a property called the [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)). Then the principle of least action states that the path that is actually taken is the one that extremises the action. For  light ray the action is proportional to the time taken, so for a light ray we find that the path does indeed extremise the time taken.

However for a magnet moving in a magnetic field the action is not simply the time taken. It would be the integral of a function called the [Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) along the path. The actual path taken will minimise the action that results from this function and the action will, in general, not be equal to the time taken.

So on the one hand the answer to your question is *no* since the path won't minimise the time, but on the other hand the answer to your question is *yes* if we consider the most efficient path to be the one that minimises the action.

Comment: What about minimization of distance of the rotation path? Does least action in the case of a magnet rotating to the position of least energy in the magnetic field minimize *length* of the rotation path?

Comment: No. The Lagrangian for the rotating dipole will include the rotational KE and the cross product of the magnetic field and the dipole moment. It won't simply be proportional to the angle rotated.